# How can I show quantity field in Ubercart on Drupal site

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, ubercart

I have module Ubercart for Drupal.

I would like to have showed box for QUANTITY, but I can't find it in view setting for fields or in administration for cart "admin/store/settings/cart" or in section manage display for product content type.

Is it possible? thanks

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:
Administer » Store administration » Configuration » Product settings where it has a check box "Display an optional quantity field in the Add to Cart form."

Comment: AAAAHHH I see it right now under PRODUCT SETTING. Sorry and thanks,